# Jquery. Convert String to number and add 1

Tags: jquery

This is what I tried:

```
<script>
var title = $("div.example");
var parts = title.split(' - ');
var parts2 = +parts[0];
var convert = parts2 + 1;
$("div.example").replace(parts2 , convert);
</script>
```

Comment: What was the output? And what did you expect your output to be? http://www.sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

`val()` is not valid. Remove it. Also, coerce to an int by prepending with `+`

```js
var title = "3 - 1";
var parts = title.split(' - ');
var convert = +parts[0] + 1;
console.log(convert);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close but val() is incorrect and also need to convert to number since `number + string` just concatenates the two as string and would be `"31"`

Try:

```
var title = "3 - 1";
var parts = title.split(' - ');
var convert = +parts[0] + 1;
alert(convert);
```

Comment: Oh ok, Didn't know you could convert it using an expression.

Comment: not really , you need to provide written explanation of what you are now trying to do. Broken code that doesn't make sense isn't an adequate substitute for explanation

Comment: I thought it was obvious That I was trying to replace the old string with the new string...

Comment: anywhere in the html within that container? It's not as obvious as you might think since that value could be in and image src which changing it would break image path, or in attributes within the container. A proper question would provide a proper description...not assumptions

Comment: No, it's simply replacing text within <p> tags.
Text: "3 - 1"
expected output: "4 - 1"
output: "3 - 1"

Comment: create a regex and loop over the p tags and use replace() on the text

Comment: What is that meant to do? I am targeting the div, so it should apply to all p tags?

Comment: fine then do same thing with the html instead of the text

Comment: what doesn't work? You really need to put more effort into this than just 3 words snippets as in question and expecting people to read your mind. Start a new question and before you do read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You can easily convert a string to number like that:

```
parseInt(string)
```

[Here is it](https://jsfiddle.net/04t0fL95/)